# Runtime library for clang on windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, llvm, clang

I have built **clang** with VS9 following [manual](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#buildWindows).

I have compiled code:

```
void foo()
{
    try
    {
        throw 1;
    }
    catch(int)
    {}
}
```

to object file. It has external dependencies:

```
___cxa_allocate_exception
__ZTIi
___cxa_throw
```

I guess that these comes from runtime library. But which one should I use? Should I build libc++? Is it stable?

PS: I don't want to have any dependency on cygwin/mingw

PPS: but seems like mingw is what I need... is it only viable option?

Comment: I do hope you don't throw `int`s outside little test scripts...

Comment: @AlexChamberlain of course, that is just test for runtime dependency

Answer (score 0):

You need C++ ABI library. libc++ won't help you here. You need either libc++abi or libsupc++ or something similar.

Comment: http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/ : Platform Support - Darwin. Does  **libsupc++** work on windows?

Comment: libsupc++ is a part of libstdc++. So, yes, it does.